# changing all tomcat ports

Tags: tomcat, port, multiple-instances

Is there anyway to change all tomcat ports so that running multiple versions of tomcat on the same machine never conflicts? Maybe have some kind of 'incrementer' which will increment all ports by that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change all the ports in server.xml. There is no automatic mechanism.